# How can I add a button column to datagrid object

Tags: javascript, aspxgridview

I want to add a button column to data grid object. I fill the data table in aspx.cs file. Our frame work is .Net Webform structure. How can I do this? My grid is as follows:

```
        <div id="divSGKTecrube" runat="server">
            <iskurControls:IskurGridView runat="server"
                ID="ctlGridSgkTecrube"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                EmptyDataText="Tecrübe Bilginiz Bulunmamaktadır."
                EnableViewState="true"
                CssClass="table table-bordered table-condensed text-small">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ISYERISICILNO" HeaderText="İşyeri Sicil No">
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ISYERIADI" HeaderText="İşyeri Adı">
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="MESLEKKODU" HeaderText="Meslek Kodu">
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="MESLEK" HeaderText="Meslek">
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SURE" HeaderText="Süre">
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="BASLANGICTARIHI" HeaderText="Baş Tar">
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="BITISTARIHI" HeaderText="Bit Tar">
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                </Columns>
                <PagerStyle CssClass="grid-PagerStyle"></PagerStyle>
                <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="grid-SelectedRowStyle"></SelectedRowStyle>
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="grid-HeaderStyle"></HeaderStyle>
                <EditRowStyle CssClass="grid-EditRowStyle"></EditRowStyle>
                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="grid-AlternatingRowStyle"></AlternatingRowStyle>
                <FooterStyle CssClass="grid-FooterStyle"></FooterStyle>
                <RowStyle CssClass="grid-RowStyle"></RowStyle>
                <EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="grid-EmptyRow" />
            </iskurControls:IskurGridView>
            <div style="text-align: center">
                <kaleCustomControls:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" VisibleIfNoNeed="False" PagerButtons="NextPrevious" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you can add a button column to your grid:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actions">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="EditRow" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

In your **aspx.cs** file, you'll need to handle the commands. You can use the RowCommand event of the IskurGridView to do this:

```
protected void ctlGridSgkTecrube_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "EditRow")
    {
        // Handle edit logic
        int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        // Access data for the selected row
    }
    else if (e.CommandName == "DeleteRow")
    {
        // Handle delete logic
        int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        // Delete data for the selected row
    }
}
```

Remember to add the RowCommand event handler to your IskurGridView:

```
<iskurControls:IskurGridView runat="server"
    ID="ctlGridSgkTecrube"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    OnRowCommand="ctlGridSgkTecrube_RowCommand"
    <!-- ... -->
>
    <!-- Columns definition -->
</iskurControls:IskurGridView>
```